# Access user's USB-connected peripheral/device over the internet on an ASP.NET web application

Tags: c#, usb, libusb

I was wondering, is it possible to take control of an end-user's USB-connected device or peripheral from an ASP.NET web application via C# with the libUsbDotNet library?

In other words, be able to control certain functions of USB devices from a website?

I would think that would be pretty cool.

Comment: that wouldn't be cool... it'd open up a flood gate for hackers to go wild.

Comment: OK, nvmd then, _my bad_.  All I was saying was that it would be kind of cool to be able to control client USB devices from a website.

Answer (score 1):

You've got to keep in mind that browser are working to keep you from doing this.

You would actually have to write an ActiveX Component, to be able to do something like this.

Answer (score 1):

no. for many reasons.

the most salient reason that 'no' is the answer to your question is that the lib runs on the server, not the client.

a more pragmatic reason is that browsers are engineered to be sandboxed. creating an activeX component is the only realistic way around this but the technology and deployment is fraught with complications and then you have to consider the limited support for activex across browser/platforms.